# How do I import, edit, and replace text in a txt file?

Tags: javascript, html

Using a client side script in a webpage (no server code), like javascript, how do I import, edit, and replace text in a txt file? I am simply trying to use two variables (Name and IP Address) and replace them in a text file. The existing text file is very long and I would like to automate this process. It would be nice for the script to also automatically create a new text file each time it is submitted. THANKS!

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>TExt File Changer v1</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function findaNamendReplaceAll() {
  var findaName = "Site_Name";
  var findaCIP = "192.168.0.5";
  var replaceaName = document.myInput.replaceWithName.value;
  var replaceaCIP = document.myInput.replaceWithCIP.value;
  var fulltexta = document.myInput.fulltext.value;
/* 
  var nr = new RegExp(findaName,"ig");
  var tmp = fulltexta.replace(/Site_Name/gi, replaceaName).replace(/192.168.0.5        /gi,replaceaCIP); 
  document.myInput.fulltext.value = tmp;
*/  

  document.myInput.fulltext.value = fulltexta.replace(/Site_Name/gi, replaceaName).replace(/192.168.0.5/gi,replaceaCIP);
}


var str     += ‘SECTION ethernet’/n;
   str      += ‘ETHERNET=UP’/n;
   str      += ‘BOOTP=server’/n;    
   str      += ‘HOSTNAME=Site_Name’/n;
   str      += ‘IPADDR=192.168.0.4’/n;
   str      += ‘NETMASK=255.255.255.0’/n;
   str      += ‘DNS=‘/n;
   str      += ‘DHCP_RANGE_L=192.168.0.20’/n;
   str      += ‘DHCP_RANGE_U=192.168.0.100’/n;
   str      += ‘SEARCH=‘/n;
   str      += ‘ZEROCONF=YES’/n;
   str      += ‘ETH0_ADD_DEFAULT=on’/n;
   str      += ‘ENDSECTION ethernet’/n;
   str      += ‘‘;
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myInput" onsubmit="return false">
<h1>Configuration Tool</h1>

New Site Name: <input type="text" id="replaceWithName" name="replaceWithName" value="">
<br><br>
New Camera IP: <input type="text" id="replaceWithCIP" name="replaceWithCIP" value="">
<br><br>
<button onclick="findaNamendReplaceAll()">Go</button>
<br><br>

<textarea id="fulltext" name="fulltext" rows="20" cols="100">
SECTION ethernet
ETHERNET=UP
BOOTP=no
HOSTNAME=Site_Name
IPADDR=192.168.0.4
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS=
DHCP_RANGE_L=
DHCP_RANGE_U=
SEARCH=
ZEROCONF=YES
ETH0_ADD_DEFAULT=on
ENDSECTION ethernet
</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fulltext').value = ''">Clear</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fulltext').value = str">Restore</button>

</form>
</body>
</html></pre>
```

Comment: You can not access the filesystem with JavaScript. So you will need some server side script for this.

Comment: Using just HTML and JS, you can pull the text file into the browser, and you can do the find and replace, but without a server technology there would be no way to put it back on the server.

Comment: I can change the text in the textarea and then save it to a file.

Comment: Use the File API: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/ . Tutorial: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily, provided you adhere to two limitations.

1) Internet Explorer on windows
2) Use of ActiveXObjects

I did a project that required assembling various data as found in excel spreadsheets. My input file was a hand-edited json file - specifying things like filenames and paths. Once the json was loaded, I used an ActiveXObject to open and control Excel in just the same manner as one would from within a VBA program.

As a result, I don't have any code to load arbitrary data from an arbitrary filename.
However, this snippet should give you enough to get started.

**Note:** The code assumes that IE still gives you a fully qualified path for any file selected with an `<input type='file'/>` Chrome, FF and Opera only give you the filename - they do not tell you which folder it resides in.

```
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}
function writeDataToFile()
{
    var mFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

    var mFile = mFSO.createtextfile(outputFilename);
    mFile.write( byId('outputTextArea').value );
    mFile.close();
    alert("text saved to '" + outputFilename + "'");
}
```